# Auth0 implmentation with .net core 2.1

Tags: auth0

Unable to create token in auth0 using C#

```
var client = new RestClient("https://domain/oauth/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"client_id\":\"#####\",\"cli``ent_secret\":\"####\",\"audience\":\"https://domain/api/v2/users\",\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Giving :

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "Service not enabled within domain: https://satyamdev.auth0.com/api/v2/users/"
}
```

Comment: Have you ever configure "Cors"?, I Think this is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are providing undefined API identifier (audience) in the request. The audience parameter should be https://[domain].auth0.com/api/v2/.

Example curl command:

Executing client credential Grant type to get the token.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://[Domain].auth0.com/oauth/token'  \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"grant_type":"client_credentials","client_id":"[Client ID]","client_secret": "[Client secret]","audience": "https://[Domain].auth0.com/api/v2/"}'
```

After getting the token you can make an HTTP get request to endpoint [/api/v2/users/{id}](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/get_users_by_id) to get the whole user profile.

Curl Command:

```
curl -X GET \
--url "https://[Domain].auth0.com/api/v2/users" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization:Bearer [Token]"
```

In Dotnet core 2.1, you can try the following to get the token and use the token to get the users:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ClientCredentials {
    class Program {
        private static string accessToken;
        private static async Task Main (string[] args) {
            await ClientCredentialsFlow ();
            await GetUsers ();
            // await CreateUser();
        }

        protected static async Task ClientCredentialsFlow () {

            var body = new Model {
                grant_type = "client_credentials",
                client_id = "[client id]",
                client_secret = "[client secret]",
                audience = "https://[domain].auth0.com/api/v2/"
            };

            using (var client = new HttpClient ()) {
                var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (body);
                var stringContent = new StringContent (content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var res = await client.PostAsync ("https://[domain].auth0.com/oauth/token", stringContent);
                var responseBody = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
                var deserilizeBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResponseModel> (responseBody);
                accessToken = deserilizeBody.access_token;
                Console.WriteLine (accessToken);

            }

        }
        protected static async Task GetUsers () {
            using (var client = new HttpClient ()) {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue ("Bearer", accessToken);
                var response = await client.GetAsync ("https://[domain].auth0.com/api/v2/users");
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
                Console.WriteLine ("==============================");
                Console.WriteLine (responseBody);

            }
        }

        internal class Model {

            public string grant_type { get; set; }
            public string client_id { get; set; }
            public string client_secret { get; set; }
            public string audience { get; set; }
        }

        internal class AuthResponseModel {
            public string access_token { get; set; }
            public string scopes { get; set; }
            public string expires_in { get; set; }
            public string token_type { get; set; }
        }

        internal class User {
            public string email { get; set; }
            public bool email_verified { get; set; }
            public string connection { get; set; }
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }

        }

    }
}
```

Note: To call /api/v2/users endpoint, you need to have correct [permissions](https://auth0.com/docs/applications/machine-to-machine) (read:users).

Comment: we use " https://[domain].auth0.com/api/v2/" when , we want to create token , but I have to create user into Aouth0 DB , so that we have to call " https://[domain].auth0.com/api/v2/users" which is reserved API.